# How do LIRA/LRSP's differ from RRSP's?

Tags: canada, rrsp

I have heard of

- Locked In Retirement Accounts (LIRAs) also known as Locked-in Retirement Savings Plans (LRSPs)
- Registered Retirement Savings Plans (RRSPs)

How are they different and what are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the lock-in.  :-)

An RRSP is contributed-to when you feel like it, and money can be removed under various circumstances (including the home-buyers program).

A locked-in plan is often the result of a pension conversion upon leaving a place of employment.  When I left a company, I had three options for my pension.  Leave it, transfer it to a receiving pension plan, or convert it to a Locked-in RSP.

The premise here, at least in part, is that given there are various tax advantages to the money growing tax-free, you have therefore allowed yourself to be limited in your withdrawal options.

Hope that helps

Comment: I just came across an article at Financial Post describing some of the options that may be available for accessing locked-in plan funds.  Thought it would be useful to share here.  See http://www.financialpost.com/personal-finance/rrsp-centre/story.html?id=2559258